# How to open file correctly?

Tags: c++, input

Lets assume we have INPUT.TXT file with the following content:

```
   -   
 --  --
```

Here we have 16 characters: 5 (-) and 11 ( ). But when I run this code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream input("INPUT.TXT", ios::ate | ios::binary);
    cout << input.tellg(); //returns the number of characters in file
    return 0;
}
```

I get as result 13. I realized that this is due to the fact that the spaces on the first line after the character (-) disappear. So how can I open and read this file so that these spaces do not disappear?

Comment: I can't reproduce https://wandbox.org/permlink/PqcuM12damVqRCO8

Comment: I agree. No problem with this code. `hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X "' input.txt:
20 20 20 2D 20 20 20 20 0A 20 2D 2D 20 20 2D 2D 20 0A`, `./test: 18`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any kind of advanced text editor that edits or beautify your texts at the time of saving it? I've run the same code on my device and I got the perfect output.

But I tried to save INPUT.TXT using Code::Blocks first. And I found out that Code::Blocks used to remove the trailing spaces during saving.

Use a simple editor that doesn't manipulate your data.

[image: Here's my output]

Comment: Ty very much! It's so strange, I ran Java code in Intellij IDEA with the same file and it worked, but in CLion I got this problem with spaces because of CLion text editor...